# How do I find sites using ubercart marketplace module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, ubercart, marketplace

I want to find sites using ubercart marketplace module because I want to see how it looks and inspiration on how do I make my site.

Is there any google search syntax for finding such sites?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how will you get such list of sites that are using Ubercart  marketplace.

There are two live sites links given on [Ubercart Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace)-Drupal Project Page

These two live sites are using the same module, one is not working but the second link is perfectly fine.

You may visit that site to check.
Hope this will give you an idea, for what you are looking for.